# Problem about querying the photo_tag using FQL on facebook?

Tags: facebook, asp-classic, facebook-fql, photo-tagging

I have an application which wanting to show the statistics about a friend who got tagged in a photo. The outcome seems odd.

e.g. I have a friend A. A is a friend of B but B isn't my friend. B has a photo and tag A to his photo. When my facebook application runs, I cannot see how many tagged photo applied on A. Is it because B is not my friend so I can't see A got tagged. Even when A tagged himself on B's photo, I still can't see the photo_tag of A.

I can query the photo_tag of user A if the photo owned by A either tagged by A or B.

Answer (score 1):

Please try ading extended permission friends_tag_phtos and see whether that retrieves friend A's tagged photos by B